# появилось 500+ ошибок после случайного удаления dataset в winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2019

как исправить данную ошибку?
работала над одной формой, в которой не высвечивалось нужное представление и удалила созданное (ненужное), увидела второе с таким же названием (сбитая нумерация) и теперь ошибка даже после закрытия VS не исчезает...
а завтра нужно все сдавать... не с нуля же все делать......[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если удалить viewdataset1 и оставить только viewdataset, то ошибка может исправиться или все станет только хуже?

Comment: У вас дубликат кода, partial класс. Он в нескольких файлах у вас.

Comment: после удаления полностью кода в viewdataset1.designer.cs остается только две ошибки, но я не вижу способа их решения. ошибки: 1. неоднозначность след. методов или свойств ChiDataSet.ChiDataSet() и ChiDataSet.ChiDataSet(), 2. Неоднозначность между ChiDataSet.SchemaSerializationMode и ChiDataSet.SchemaSerializationMode

Comment: Вообще в designer.cs файлы руками лазить не стоит, они для дизайнера.

Comment: Эти 2 ошибки указывают на дубликаты методов в коде. Источник проблемы всё тот же.

Comment: я не лезла изначально, просто все полетело из-за удаления одного dataset и все ошибки появились как раз в designer.cs.

Comment: Вы можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как решить эту проблему? в этой части VS я вообще ноль

Comment: Научитесь использовать систему контроля версий, например git. Как решить - F12 переход к определению. Поставьте курсор на ошибочный код, нажмите.

Comment: У вас может быть 2 неймспейса с одинаковым классом, в месте ошибки они подключены оба. Либо отключите лишний неймспейс, либо удалите лишний код, либо укажите правильный неймспейс в месте вызова явно.

Comment: Был бы git, проблема бы решалась простым откатом к предыдущему коммиту, одной командой в консоль гита. Считайте, что это звоночек.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы: полное удаление копии dataset из проекта (designer.cs особенно)